# Pagination won't work using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Good day! I am using jQuery Tablesorter to do pagination in a table. However, after following what was done [here](https://www.novell.com/communities/coolsolutions/jquery-tablesorter-pagination-and-sorting-made-simple/), my table still won't paginate. When I change the limit, the number of rows in the table doesn't change. I'm using Play Framework btw.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Please help me figure this out. Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** 
I just saw this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the line `.tablesorter`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function viewTags:24
(anonymous function) viewTags:24
fire jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
self.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.10.2.js:433
completed
```

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: There's also 2 jquery libraries loaded: one from tablesorter.com and other - from your local store. Btw, your second jquery lib is rather old

Comment: Please provide console logs.

Comment: I am sure some javascript dependency files are missing.There is a net tab in firebug plugin.Check that all the javascript files are loaded or there is 404 error on some files.

Comment: I tried using jsfiddle I'm not sure about this. http://jsfiddle.net/XZP6R/ @TheMohanAhuja

Comment: You need to specify tablesorter JS files in the External Resources in JSFiddle, before it would start working.

Comment: Thanks @AVK but I think those 2 are different. One is `jquery.tablesorter.js` and the other one is `jquery.tablesorter.pager.js`.

Comment: Thanks @Innovation but there are no `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` right now.

Comment: Thanks here is the revised jsfiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/XZP6R/3/`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XZP6R/4/ check this

Comment: @susheel, the pagination does not work very well there

Comment: i just gave an example so that issue can be solved from here

Comment: Cool the jsfiddle works when I added @susheel's. http://jsfiddle.net/XZP6R/5/ But I tried it on mine but still doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at this [jsfiddle.net/andreyvk/BSLXY/](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyvk/BSLXY/)

Comment: Thanks @AVK for the pagesize select. But I can't pin point why mine is not working. I also tried loading the fiddle's external resources' URL. No 404 error too but still doesn't work.

Comment: @AVL
no need of .change(); it should work normally without that

Comment: Thanks @AVK but I just saw this error (it also existed the whole for sure) `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the line `.tablesorter`

Comment: @susheel you can try my fiddle with and without it. The pager doesnt work equally well

Comment: you need to pass size:5 option..check my answer and fiddle @AVK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/XZP6R/9/**

**include the js in order:**

1. latest jquery
2. tablesorter js
3. tablesorter pagination js

**Follow the exact html syntax for pager**:

**something like this:**

```
<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

**This is normal way of doing as per documentation and it works well:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table") 
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra'] }) 
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"),size:5}); 
});
```

**NOTE:**

multiple jquery instances in same page creates this error. please remove the duplicate instances.

Comment: accept the changes in your question and try that way. I am expecting that you are pointing correctly to tablesorter.js in your location

Comment: Still the `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in `tablesorter`. But the error interface-wise, none. Thanks

Comment: your error simple says you have included jquery twice...check your page if you have included it somewhere..by the way did you include the js as i corrected in your question ?

Comment: even close td tags properly

Comment: Yes, I followed every instruction you provided, thanks. But the same old error persists.

Comment: remove line number 44 in view source..as i expected second time jquery declared in same page

Comment: why is the style sheet and js floating on the top before doctype can you bring that to head.

Comment: It is because the file where line 44 belongs to is a separate `scala.html`. Thank you so much I removed that line and I just encountered a few errors regarding `msie` and I just imported `jQuery Migrate plug-in` and voila, it now paginates! Thank you very much for your patience and help!